# File API: Directories and System -- discontinued... what does that mean?

Tags: javascript, file, local-storage

I see, as of April 24, 2014 http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/ that work on the File API has been discontinued. This raises two questions:
1. does it have any implications for createObjectURL() for reading local files? (I would suppose not, since that seems to be pretty widely implemented)
2. Suppose one wanted to locally save the output of a web app (like a drawing program) to a file. How would one do that and does the April 24 statement have implications toward the ability to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misread the statement. The File Api is not discontinued, just that one document was discountinued. See here: http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html. It has no mention of the Api being discontinued, and testing the Api it doesn't seem so.